# whats the difference between releasing an object inside dealloc or releasing in the same method where we init it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,
I am working on optimizing my iphone project for proper memory management. 
my question is:

what's the difference between releasing an object inside dealloc or releasing in the same method where we init it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you want to release an object as close to the point in the code where you initialize it as possible. If you have local variables in a method that you are `init`-ing, you release them before the method returns.

This, however, is not possible with instance variables, since they stick around with the objects; thus, you release them in a `dealloc` method.